# Retrieve number from string using Regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to retrieve a number from a string wherever the number starts with 8,9 or 6 and length of the number should be  8 OR 9 Characters. E.g 92000000,9200 0000,9200-0000.

Comment: This is a very specific request. Do you have any thoughts as to how it might be satisfied?

Comment: i am using this Regex (?<!\d)[896]\d{7}(?!\d) and retrieve number in this format 92000000. but i want to retrieve this two format 9200 0000,9200-0000 also.

Comment: @user1872289 `(?<!\d)[896]\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}(?!\d)` try this..

Comment: What's so terrible about this question that it deserves -3 rep ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: `(?<!\d)([896]\d{3})(?:[-\s]?)(\d{4})(?!\d)`.

The `(?:[-\s]?)` eats the optional delimiters space or dash as a non-capturing group.

You get your number by concatenating the match groups 1 and 2:

```
var input = new string[] {
    "81000000", "92000000", "9200 0000", "9200-0000"
};
var regex = new Regex (@"(?<!\d)([896]\d{3})(?:[-\s]?)(\d{4})(?!\d)");
foreach (var str in input) {
    var match = regex.Match (str);
    Console.WriteLine ("TEST: {0} {1} - {2}", str, match.Success,
                       match.Groups [1].Value + match.Groups [2].Value);
}
```

I have also tried `(?<!\d)([896]\d{3}(?:[-\s]?)\d{4})(?!\d)` and that won't remove the delimiter character from the match result.

Comment: Or, even better, because it skips delimiter in whatever place it will be, creating 8 captures (like 680 065 45): (?<!\d)([896])(?:[-\s]*)([\d])(?:[-\s]*)([\d])(?:[-\s]*)([\d])(?:[-\s]*)([\d])(?:[-\s]*)([\d])(?:[-\s]*)([\d])(?:[-\s]*)([\d])(?!\d)

Comment: Martin Baulig - I want also retrieve number from a string in this format also  8100000092000000 output will be81000000,92000000. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex:

```
(?<!\d)[896]\d{3}([- ]?)\d{4}(?!\d)
```

Try to solve using **[Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)** from next time.

Cheers.

Comment: Since the guy wants to extract the number without the delimiter, you'd also need to put these numbers into capture groups, like in my answer.